# Pop up at bottom of screen when double tap home button. iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, maps

I have never seen this before and wondered how it would be possible to recreate. I have an app I am working on that uses maps.

This is from Shpok. 
It shows a pop up at the bottom of the screen when double pressing the home button.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is simply creating an `NSUserActivity` and setting the [`mapItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity/1690596-mapitem) property.

Something like:

```
    let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "my.domain.activity.name")
    activity.title = "Some Title"
    activity.mapItem = anInstanceOfMKMapItem
    activity.becomeCurrent()
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the answer this helped a great deal for me, I didn't even know where to start before this.